# Is field splitting and filename expansion turn off in RHS of variable assignment portable?

Tags: shell, posix

In most POSIX compliant shell like `bash`. `ksh`, `dash`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, when variable assignment occur, field splitting and filename expansion (and brace expansion if the shell supports) are not performed in RHS of assignment:

```
$ IFS=/
$ a=1/2
# Field splitting and filename expansion turned off here
$ b=$a
$ IFS=
$ printf '%s\n' $b
1/2
```

Some shell's documentation ([bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters), [ksh](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html)) mentioned about this, but [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_22) didn't.

I can see this behavior in most POSIX compliant shell, so I wonder is it portable since when POSIX documentation does not specify it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on where you look at. From [Chapter 2, Section 9.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value.

I would assume that this list is exhaustive, and since [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) is not mentioned, the lack of field splitting is POSIX-specified.