# echo result from subshell in zsh

Tags: zsh, echo, subshell

In zsh, the following 2 commands results differently:

```
a=$(</etc/hosts) && echo $a
echo $(</etc/hosts)
```

The 1st prints contents line by line, while the 2nd prints contents as a whole in one single line.

I guess it is because the subshell returns result line by line to the main `echo` process, but I can not confirm that.

Someone can help me to clear that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, [unquoted variables are not automatically split and glob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), while [unquoted command substitution will be split](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) into words using values in `IFS`.

In your case, the first command saved content of file `/etc/hosts` to variable `a`, `echo $a` prints value of `a` variable without split and glob, you get the contents of `/etc/hosts` ([split and glob are not performed in RHS of variable assignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178294/38906)).

`echo $(</etc/hosts)` used unquoted command substitution, the result will be split into words, so you get content of `/etc/hosts` as all words delimited by space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in the unquoted command substitution,  the newlines are replaced by spaces.

Comment: Yes, because newline is also in `IFS` by default. You can read more [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05)

Comment: Got it, and I'm reading it. Thanks for helping me on my first SE question :D