# Any problem assigning one variable to another in shell without using quotes?

Tags: shell, quoting, posix, assignment

This question is about *assigning* the entire contents of one variable to another variable.

Variable is not being *used* (sent to `echo`, etc.)

No [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) is being done during the assignment.

My question also pertains only to POSIX shell (no arrays being used here).

```
error="You have an error in your input"

newVar="$error"
# vs.
newVar=$error
#         ↑
#         └─This assignment is the question. It doesn't seem that quotes are
#           needed here in order to assign the entire contents of $error to
#           a new variable.

#                 ┌─(But quotes are required when they're used.)
#                 ↓
printf "%s\n" "$error"
# => You have an error in your input
printf "%s\n" "$newVar"
# => You have an error in your input
```

Are there any gotchas I'm missing in just writing `newVar=$error`?

**Update**:

Regardless of what's in `$error`, I want to know will that same data carry over into `$newVar` without throwing any errors or mangling the data.

```
$ error="Test * ${1} \n [!a] [[:punct:]] ./test \t \n \\"
$ newVar=$error
#       ↑
#       └─Does this step ever fail or cause the two variables to differ?
$ echo "$error"
Test *  \n [!a] [[:punct:]] ./test \t \n \
$ echo "$newVar"
Test *  \n [!a] [[:punct:]] ./test \t \n \
```

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178294/38906).

Comment: tangentially, you may be misunderstanding the action of `printf` -- if you give it one "Argument no matter how many spaces, in quotes" then it will print the formatted values only once. If you instead give printf an unquoted variable with spaces in it, then it will repeat the format string for each.

Comment: If you're going to play with edge cases, you should probably stick to `printf "%s\n" "$var"`, because `echo "$var"` is less predictable/reliable when `$var` begins with dash (**`-`**) or contains backslash (``\``).  (And of course `printf "$var"` is unforgiving if `$var` contains percent (`%`) or backslash (``\``).)

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin No, that question only touches this subject in passing. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary might be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

In Bourne-like shells (if we forget about bugs<sup>1</sup> in some old implementations of some shells)

```
var=$otherVar
```

is fine. You're assigning to a scalar variable, so there can't be glob+splitting here, so you don't need to write it `var="$otherVar"` (though the quotes don't harm here).

An exception is for:

```
var=$*
```

and:

```
var=$@
```

You should only use `var="$*"`. The behaviour of `var=$@ var=$* var="$@"` varies among shells when the first character of `$IFS` is not space.

Of course, in:

```
array=("$var")
```

You do need the quotes, as otherwise, the array elements would be assigned the result of the split+globbing of `$var`.

Also note that you need the quotes in:

```
export var="$otherVar"
```

with many shells (in them, here, it's a simple command, so split+glob occurs).

And in:

```
env var="$otherVar" cmd
```

Or

```
awk -v var="$otherVar"...
```

If in doubt, use the quotes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some old versions of `zsh` had an issue with backslash in front of wildcard characters when in `sh` emulation:

```
$ (a='\*' exec -a sh zsh-3.1.9 -c 'b=$a; printf "%s\n" "$b"')
*
$ (a='\*' exec -a sh zsh-3.1.9 -c 'b="$a"; printf "%s\n" "$b"')
\*
```

That was fixed a long time ago.