# Ask for a password in POSIX-compliant shell?

Tags: shell, scripting, password, posix

When I want to ask for a password in a `bash` script, I do that :

```
read -s
```

...but when I run `bash` in POSIX mode, with `sh`, the `-s` option is rejected:

```
$ read -s
sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s
```

How do I securely ask for an input with a POSIX-compliant command ?

Comment: One the possible ways is described in this answer on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28393320/3691891

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
read_password() {
  REPLY="$(
    # always read from the tty even when redirected:
    exec < /dev/tty || exit # || exit only needed for bash

    # save current tty settings:
    tty_settings=$(stty -g) || exit

    # schedule restore of the settings on exit of that subshell
    # or on receiving SIGINT or SIGTERM:
    trap 'stty "$tty_settings"' EXIT INT TERM

    # disable terminal local echo
    stty -echo || exit

    # prompt on tty
    printf "Password: " > /dev/tty

    # read password as one line, record exit status
    IFS= read -r password; ret=$?

    # display a newline to visually acknowledge the entered password
    echo > /dev/tty

    # return the password for $REPLY
    printf '%s\n' "$password"
    exit "$ret"
  )"
}
```

Note  that for those shells (ksh88, mksh and most other pdksh-derived shells) where `printf` is not builtin, the password would appear in clear in the `ps` output (for a few microseconds) or may show up in some audit logs if all command invocations with their parameters are audited. In those shells however, you can replace it with `print -r -- "$password"`.

In any case [`echo` is generally not an option](/q/65803).

Another POSIX-compliant one that doesn't involve revealing the password in the `ps` output (but might end up having it written onto permanent storage) is:

```
cat << EOF
$password
EOF
```

Also note that zsh's `IFS= read -rs 'pass?Password: '` or bash's `IFS= read -rsp 'Password: ' pass` issue the `Password:` prompt on stderr. So with those, you might want to add a `2> /dev/tty` to make sure the prompt goes to the controlling terminal.

In any case, [make sure you don't forget the `IFS=` and `-r`](/q/209123).

Comment: Might `cat` + heredoc be a safer alternative to the `printf`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman here docs are written as temporary files in most shells while printf is built in most shells. I'm not sure which is best.

Comment: @hildred, note that [the quotes in `REPLY="$(...)"` don't harm (except for the SE syntax highlighting) but are not necessary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220386)

Comment: Thanks for showing how to save and restore the old `stty` settings.

Answer (score 26):

`read -s` is not in POSIX. If you want to be POSIX-compliant use the `stty -echo`. [`stty` and its `echo` parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) are defined in POSIX.

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -echo
printf "Password: "
read PASSWORD
stty echo
printf "\n"
```

This will work on all shells that conform to POSIX.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980713/4248931)

Comment: to highlight a point from the answer in @arkadiusz-drabczyk's comment, it'd be a good idea to trap all the signals you can in order to turn `stty echo` back on -- in case the user gets confused and hits control-C during the `read PASSWORD` section.

Comment: read the linked answer or see Stephane's answer in this thread

Comment: You shouldn't turn on echoing unconditionally, you should save and restore the old setting. Many people work in Emacs shell buffers, and this normally has echoing disabled because Emacs is doing the echoing itself. The other answer shows how to do this.