# Hide input for a command

Tags: bash, password

*Updated as original was unclear.*

I'm setting up postfix on a computer to work with my email's SMTP.

I don't want to enter my credentials in plain text, especially when typing in public.

Is it possible to make bash not show my input for a command or two?

*Example:
I'm entering a series of commands and then I want to echo a username and password into a config file.*

*I'd like to quickly go into a mode where my input isn't shown on screen, then easily leave that mode with `ctl+c`.*

Comment: You mean enter a password into a variable without it being seen on-screen?

Comment: Like this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222974/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller kind of I'm just typing in terminal `GMAIL_PASSWORD=secret` maybe I should write a small script that asks for the env name and then password.

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks but I don't think that Q/A is at all helpful for my work-flow. I'm not writing a script. I've just noticed often I have a command or two I don't want to be seen by someone looking over my shoulder. I updated the text.

Comment: The answers that Jeff linked to apply equally to interactive use as when used in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `stty` command:

```
stty -echo
```

To re-enable echoing of terminal input:

```
stty echo
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash: read is the command and the relevant option is (from man bash):

> -s     Silent mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset password
prompt="Enter Password:"
while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
do
    if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    prompt='*'
    password+="$char"
done
echo
echo "Done. Password=$password"
```

But better to not echo anything as using asterisks allows others to see the lenght of the password.

Comment: Might more directly solve the OP's problem by reading the whole variable at once.

Comment: Reading in one go allows interpretation of some characters. As an specific example, the key backspace removes one character from the string. Others are also possible. One character at a time allow the most precise capture of the string of characters typed. @JeffSchaller