# Script to change $HOME in path to tilde ~

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I tried:
$ echo $HOME | sed 's/$HOME/~/g

but this didn't work, perhaps because of forward slashes?

Does anyone have a script to do this either or:

- using bash builtins
- using sed

Thank you

Comment: `echo $HOME | sed "s;$HOME;~;"`

Comment: also please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5930671/4023950 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399407/72456 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/72456 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671/72456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things are preventing your command from working.

First, bash will never perform variable expansion (nor command expansion, etc.) inside single quotes.  You'll need to use double quotes.

Also, it is highly likely that `$HOME` contains at least one slash, so using the slash symbol in your `sed` command as the delimiter between the target and replacement strings means you need to escape any slashes present in `$HOME`:

```
$ echo $HOME | sed "s/${HOME//\//\\\/}/~/"
~
```

Responding to your comment below, yes, you can also use `bash`'s string variable operators to accomplish this, and somewhat more concisely at that:

```
$ echo $A
/home/jim/screenshot.png
$ echo "${A/$HOME/\~}" 
~/screenshot.png
```

Comment: Beside the fact that echoing $HOME unquoted will get expanded to no longer say `$HOME`...

Comment: Thanks it looks like quoting was causing the issue

Comment: @Jim L.  I have a note from before that newPD="${1/#$HOME/~}" may have worked but I'm not sure how.  Still reading the bash man page...