# How to preserve the newline character (\n) when capture output of a command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, newlines, command-substitution

As a simple example, I have a bunch of source code files. I want to store the "head" command output to a variable for all these files.

I tried:

```
output=$(head $file)
```

but what happened is that this automatically trimmed all `\n` characters when storing the output to a variable.

How do I store the command output as is without removing `\n` characters?

Comment: You mean the leading and trailing newlines was trimmed, or only the trailing ones?

Comment: nitpick: `\n` is Line Feed, not Carriage Return

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a known flaw of "command expansion" `$(...)` or `` `...` `` that the last newline is trimmed.

If that is your case:

```
$ output="$(head -- "$file"; echo x)"     ### capture the text with an x added.
$ output="${output%?}"                    ### remove the last character (the x).
```

Will correct the value of output.

Comment: Also, outputting the value with e.g. `echo` would never preserve the internal newlines if the variable expansion wasn't quoted. See e.g. the difference between `echo $multiline` and `echo "$multiline"`.  Also: [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Hi :-) I would say "the last newlines are trimmed". Am I right ?

Comment: You could avoid the need to remove `x` by using `$ output=$(head -- "$file"; echo '')"` (i.e. echo an empty string, will still make `echo` print the newline).

Comment: Related: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution (Command substitutions strip all trailing newlines from the output of the command inside them).

Comment: "the last newline is trimmed" incorrectly implies that command substitution trims at most _one_ trailing newline, when, in reality, "sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution" are removed. – [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)

Answer (score 12):

`output=$(head $file)` keeps *embedded* newlines in the value of `output`, and trims *all* trailing newlines.

It's how you reference the variable that makes the difference.

Placing the variable reference within double quotes, for example:

```
echo "$output"
```

prints the embedded newlines, but *not* the trailing newlines, which were deleted by the command expansion `$(...)`.

This works because the shell interprets only dollar sign, command expansion (back quotes and `$(...)`), and back slashes within double quotes; the shell does not interpret whitespace (including newlines) as field separators when inside double quotes.

Comment: No, adding quotes in the RHS of assignment make no difference. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178294/38906

Comment: Command substitution does eat up trailing newlines.

Comment: How I set the variable didn't help but how I used it did which is why I like this answer.

Answer (score 3):

To also preserve the exit status:

```
output=$(head < "$file"; r=$?; echo /; exit "$r")
exit_status=$?
output=${output%/}
```

Note that using `/` is safer than `x` as there are some character sets used by some locales where the encoding of some characters end in the encoding of `x` (while the encoding of `/` would generally not be found in other characters as that would make path lookup problematic for instance).