# Preserve presence of last newline when assigning to variable

Tags: bash, string

In bash, when an output is captured into variable using `$(...)`, an annoying newline is appended. However, I have an output that sometimes ends in a newline, and sometimes not. I want the output to be captured as-is.

In my real problem, the strings may contain several lines, but the last may or may not close with a newline, and this property should be preserved.

In the style of [this answer at Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248226/how-to-preserve-the-newline-character-n-when-capture-output-of-a-command-in-a), my minimal working example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

newlinetest() {
    if [ "$1" = 'with' ]; then
        printf '%s\n' 'Text with newline'
    else
        printf '%s' 'Text without newline'
    fi
}

s="$(newlinetest with ; printf '%s' 'x')"
s="${s%?}"
printf '%s%s%s\n' '(' "${s}" ')'
s="$(newlinetest without ; printf '%s' 'x')"
s="${s%?}"
printf '%s%s%s\n' '(' "${s}" ')'
```

It does what it should do, but IMHO this looks like an ugly hack. Is there any other elegant way to solve this? Maybe something that involves `mapfile` or `read`? A solution without external tools would be very welcome.

Comment: What about Gilles' solution in the question you linked?

Comment: @Jesse_b This is more or less what he's using, but with `printf` instead of `echo`, which makes it more wordy.  I'm unsure what's a "hack" about it though.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yeah it seems like this is just an obfuscated way to use the solution Gilles suggested and then requesting to deobfuscate it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Well, `echo x` appends the letter *x* followed by a newline. The newline gets trimmed by `$()`, and afterwards the *x* is removed. IMHO, the obvious newline makes the variant with `echo` even more obfuscated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, command substitution removes trailing newlines, it doesn't append them. But if you use `echo` to print the variable later, it adds one by default.

Adding a trailing `x` or such is indeed somewhat hackish, but it's probably the easiest way, and works in all shells. You can make it somewhat shorter by using `echo x` instead of `printf '%s' 'x'`.

Since you mention `read`, you could use something like this (in Bash), too:

```
IFS= read -rd '' var < <(newlinetest with)
```

I'll leave it to you to decide if that's more pretty than this:

```
var=$(newlinetest with; echo x)
var=${var%x}
```

Though there is a potential performance difference between the two. In the first one, the process substitution creates a pipe, which `read` reads from *one byte at a time* to avoid overrunning a delimiter (That's not relevant here, but the shell doesn't know that.) The command substitution will read in larger blocks, and is therefore likely to be faster with a large output.

Comment: ah, setting `-d` to empty string -- I missed that possibility. IMHO, it is more intuitive.

Comment: @rexkogitans, actually, Bash uses the NUL byte (`\0`) as the delimiter with `-d ""`. That's close to having no delimiter at all, since variables in Bash can't contain NULs anyway. About that process substitution, there's a potential performance issue which I just realized, see edit.

Comment: `read` is a performance issue on its own, but in this case I prefer to care for other developers who want to read the script, as I find the hack-ish solution far from obvious.