# How to retain newlines on xargs -I {}

Tags: bash, xargs

The following extracts a few dozens of lines into a variable, but they are somehow all placed together into a single line. That is, they loose the original newline character:

```
ALL_FOUND_LINES=$(find "$TEMP" -type f -name "debug.log*" | xargs -I {} grep -F "STARTING HOST " {})
```

Is there a way to retain the newline character in a statement like the one above?

Comment: How are you determining that the newline characters are *not* being retained? it sounds like you are actually asking about this [How to preserve the newline character (\n) when capture output of a command in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248226/how-to-preserve-the-newline-character-n-when-capture-output-of-a-command-in-a)

Comment: @steeldriver I determine this by examining the output of  `"$(echo -e $ALL_FOUND_LINES | tr '\n' '\|')"` -- it has only one '|' at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing this with

```
echo $ALL_FOUND_LINES
```

then I'm not surprised that all newlines are gone since the shell would split the value in `$ALL_FOUND_LINES` on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default) into words (and then further expand each word by means of filename generation (globbing)).  It does this since the expansion is unquoted.
The `echo` utility then gets a list of words that it prints on a single line.

A better test would be

```
printf '%s\n' "$ALL_FOUND_LINES"
```

Note the quoting of the variable expansion.  For the choice of `printf` over `echo`, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).

---

Your command can be improved into

```
find "$TEMP" -type f -name 'debug.log*' -exec grep -h -F 'STARTING HOST ' {} +
```

Here, instead of passing the filenames off to `xargs`, we let `find` execute `grep` directly on as many `debug.log*` files as possibly at a time.  Note that getting rid of `xargs` does not solve your newlines problem, as `xargs` had nothing to do with this. This would speed things up a bit since it involves fewer invocations of `grep`.

See also [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705).

If you need to do something with each of the found lines, then you may loop over them like this:

```bash
find "$TEMP" -type f -name 'debug.log*' -exec grep -h -F 'STARTING HOST ' {} + |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # use "$line" here (with quotes)
done
```

(or replace the while loop with whatever other processing step that you need to carry out).  So there is never a need to store all of the data in a variable as a newline-delimited string.

See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Answer (score -2):

man xargs

> ```
>    -L max-lines
>           Use at most max-lines nonblank input  lines  per  command  line.
>           Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on
>           the next input line.  Implies -x.
>
>    -l[max-lines], --max-lines[=max-lines]
>           Synonym for the -L option.  Unlike -L, the max-lines argument is
>           optional.   If  max-lines  is not specified, it defaults to one.
>           The -l option is deprecated since the POSIX  standard  specifies
>           -L instead.
> ```