# Use a wildcard in directory path

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I'm trying to write a bash script where part of a directory is a long, unknown string. I know the first part of the directory name. How do I combine the known string and the wildcard in the path? As of now, I have:

```
ID=$1;

IMP="adam@ocelot.cs.edu:/data/"$ID"/EER_DATA/$ID"*"/ImpostorScores.txt"
```

but this passes a literal `*`.

Comment: `bash` does this by default e.g. for `FOO=/*/passwd`. Is the path local (so an immediate glob expansion can happen) or is it remote?

Comment: Globbing doesn't understand hosts. This will look for a directory named 'adam@ocelot.cs.edu:` in the current directory and so on. The glob won't find a match and thefore remain as an asterisk. What's would you do with the `$IMP` variable if if did expand across hosts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: In regards to the first question, it's a remote path. Ultimately I'll be using this in an `scp` command

Comment: Globbing a remote path would require either that the filesystem be exported (NFS, FUSE-over-SSH, etc) or that a SSH is done over to the system and a glob run there.

Comment: There are two `$ID` in your string for `$IMP`. Is that as you need it?

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178294/38906

Answer (score 2):

There are several options,

1. Use NFS or FUSE-over-SSH or something to expose the remote filesystem locally, then let `bash` apply the default `FOO=/*/passwd` glob on that exported filesystem path. (ZSH has a `${~spec}` glob substitution parameter expansion, otherwise see your shell's manual.)
2. SSH over to the remote system, and do the glob there. `ssh host 'echo /*/passwd'`
3. Pass the escaped (or otherwise defanged via backslash or single quotes) glob through to the remote system, `scp host:/\*/passwd .`

Some of these options are prone to race conditions should the filename change between when the glob is done and any subsequent steps involving that (possibly changed) filename.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 1. For #2, can you provide more detail? I understand how to login to my server via ssh, but I've never used it in a shell script on my local machine. For 3, I've tried escaping and using single quotes, but it's still passing "*"

Comment: @thrig #2 is resolve the full path first then assign it to a variable. dest=$(ssh host 'echo /data/$ID/EER_DATA/$ID*'). Then use that variable, scp filename host:$dest/filename

Answer (score 0):

You can use tar over ssh,

`tar cf - filename | ssh adam@ocelot.cs.edu "cd /data/$ID/EER_DATA/$ID*; tar xf -"`

Make sure you have setup ssh-agent so it won't prompt you with the password. I don't think you can use wildcard dir with scp, not even working with a regular cp.

I've tested this on bash and zsh.

Comment: I'm trying to copy a file, not a directory. This returns the error "Not a directory". Which part should I edit?

Answer (score 0):

The right side of a "Variable Assignment" is considered quoted (no splitting or globing):

```
LESS=+'/A variable may be assigned' man bash
```

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form:
>      name=[value]
>   Word splitting is not performed, ... .  Pathname expansion is not performed.

Therefore:

```
$ var=*
$ echo "$var"
*
```

---

To get an asterisk to expand, you need to use it un-quoted:

```
var="$(echo *)"                ### Expand to the list of files on pwd.
```

In your case:

```
$ ID=one
$ IMP="$( echo "adam@ocelot.cs.edu:/data/$ID/EER_DATA/"*"/ImpostorScores.txt")"
$ echo "$IMP"
adam@ocelot.cs.edu:/data/one/EER_DATA/something/ImpostorScores.txt
```

That something will be expanded if the whole path match, that is, a tree like this actually exists:

```
$ tree adam@ocelot.cs.edu\:/
adam@ocelot.cs.edu:/
└── data
    └── one
        └── EER_DATA
            └── something
                └── ImpostorScores.txt
```

Note: I removed the second `$ID` from your source, easy to re-place.